# google closure compiler - not inlining goog lib function calls?

Tags: google-closure-compiler, google-closure-library

I wrote a JavaScrip application a few years back using the closure framework and compiler. It uses goog.require, goog.provides and goog.inherits a lot, and was working fine using the old python script to build it.

I wanted it working again so I updated the library and compiler and used my old make script. But get this.

> Closure Compiler now natively understands and orders Closure
>   dependencies and is prefererred over using this script for performing
>   JavaScript compilation. Please migrate your codebase. See:
>   https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Managing-Dependencies

I read the link provided and did not see anything wrong. So I replaced the script with this.

```
java -jar C:/closure/closure-compiler-v20160713.jar --output_manifest _manifest.txt  
--compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS --js M*.js 
--js_output_file _M_min.js
```

It compiles fine, however when running I get errors such as...

```
_M_min.js?v=4:23 Uncaught ReferenceError: goog is not defined

_M_min.js?v=4:54 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined
```

I thought the compiler unrolled all of this and did not require including the goog library at run time?

If I do include the library with "js/goog/base.js" I get goog.yb is not a function and so on. But I really did not think I needed to do this.

What am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are multiple problems:

1. You have to include closure library in your compilation as source. Adding `--js path/to/closure/**.js` will do it.
2. You need to use the [dependency management flags](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Managing-Dependencies). If you use `goog.require` and `goog.provide` in ALL of your files, you'll want `strict` mode.